# Load balanced nsupdate

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Does anybody know how to update a load balanced DNS entry on a BIND9 server using nsupdate?

Everything in DNS is setup and works, I can happily update my name server using nsupdate but I can't find any syntax to allow me to add multiple endpoints to an entry.
For example, I have an entry such as:

```
www           IN A       192.168.1.20
              IN A       192.168.1.21
              IN A       192.168.1.22
```

The 192.168.1.22 is going down for maintenance and I want to remove it from the DNS record in advance, I would like to run:

```
nsupdate [keys etc]
> server dns.example.com
> update delete www.example.com
> update add www.example.com 1 IN A 192.168.1.20 A 192.168.1.21
> send
> quit
```

Obviously manually editing the DNS file works fine, but I'd like to do this over nsupdate. If anyone can provide a way of doing this I'd be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: Having more than one CNAME violates RFC. Does that even work?

Comment: I think you may well be right, I'll change that to A records instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use multiple `update add` lines.

```
...
update add www.example.com 3600 IN A 192.168.1.20
update add www.example.com 3600 IN A 192.168.1.21
send
```

Comment: I'm an idiot! Thanks. I only tested it with CNAMEs...